# htaccess - Exception when no file is specified

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to make an .htaccess where www.domain.com/?get=1234 gets rewritten to www.domain.com/1234 , with the exceptions for files such as style.css, logo.png, etc.

This works great for all files but I can't figure out how to make an exception for www.domain.com/ directory index.php file, and simply putting index.php as an exception forces the user to include index.php in the URL which I ofcourse don't like.

Thanks in advance. My .htaccess so far:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Exceptions

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/favicon.ico
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/style.css
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/logo.png

# get Rewriting

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?get=$1 [L]

# www Rewriting

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. If you find an answer helpful, you can upvote it, as soon as you have enough reputation. If an answer solves your question, please accept it. See also [How do I ask questions here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to rewrite everything, excluding real files and directories, you can use these two [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)s as exception guards

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys. However, when i try your example of replacing the whole document (excluding the WWW-redirection part) with just RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\d+$ /?get=$0 [L] then it gives me 404 error when i try and reach for example domain.com/?get=about using domain.com/about.   .com/?get=  works but not .com/about

Comment: @Anka `domain.com/about` isn't rewritten by this rule, only numeric URL paths. Do you want all requests being rewritten, except the few you listed?

Comment: Yes, the GET value can be a-f0-9, so it will need to redirect alphanumeric to ?get= , everything which are NOT real files on the server should be rewritten. Is this possible somehow, it would be optimal. Otherwise, i'd have to go using exceptions like my original idea. How do I solve this?

Comment: OMG. This worked like a charm! Thanks a lot guys for all great answers! This was my first post on Stackoverflow and what a great first impression I got already. :-) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

So, if I figured it right... you just want to redirect "www.domain.com" to "www.domain.com/index.php" correct ?

What if you insert

```
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]
```

as the first line of the **# get rewriting** area ?